# How do I get all keys from redis matching a pattern and less than some value efficiently

Tags: python, redis

**Background** : I have used timestamp as my key with **ABC_** as a prefix, eg - 'ABC_202104231429' (in yyyymmddHHMM) format, and stored values with respect to keys in redis.

**Ques** : Now I want to find out all keys
matching ABC_ prefix and less than the current timestamp.

I already figured it out for finding all keys with a prefix effixiently using scan_iter('ABC_'), but how do I find all keys less than a certain given timestamp.

I thought of this, any other efficient way would definitely help:

```
for key in redis.scan_iter('ABC_'):
    if key < 'ABC_' + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M"):
        print(key)
```

Comment: Will there be any key in redis which is greater than current timestamp? Say it’s 5pm right now and you scan for all keys with ABC_ as prefix, this scan will give you everything there is till 5pm, or will Redis have keys beyond 5pm too?

Comment: @AnkitSahay i have modified the requirement. Say, i want to find all the keys less than a certain timestamp, lets call it X, so yes there can be keys greater than X.